# I get following error when sending a mail using zend frame work. I also included my code

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'
with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'  
in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace:  
 #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):
    Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
 #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97):
    Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
 #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Application.php(366): 
    Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
 #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\intern\lc.intern\public\index.php(26):
    Zend_Application->run()
 #4 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception'
 with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'
   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):
    Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
   #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Application\B
     in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

my code for sending mail is as follows:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'my name')
         ->setFrom('myemanil@gmail.com', 'my name')
         ->setSubject('My Subject')
         ->setBodyText('Email Body')
         ->send();
```

when I remove the last line i.e., send() then it works fine , but to send a mail we require send() :-P

I'm stuck here ...

please help me ...

thanks in advance

Comment: Check for the correct path to your Controller directory.

Comment: everything works fine dude , except this error , so I hope no problem with controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like two things happening here:

1. The `send()` method is throwing an exception. Since you are not specifying a `$transport` object, it is attempting to use standard sendmail as a default. It looks like you are using Windows. Do you have sendmail installed? I, too, get exceptions when sending on my local Windows dev environment. Maybe test with an smtp-based transport?
2. The thrown exception is triggering the error handler, so it is looking for the `ErrorController::errorAction()`. The message you see is the result of a missing or incorrectly placed `ErrorController`.

Just thinking out loud.

Comment: you're right sir ! my file is missing and I recognised the problem , but still I have another problem which I posted in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508888/zend-framework-zend-mail-function-error-included-code

Comment: sir , still my mail function is not working sir, I reposted my updated code @ the following link please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508888/zend-framework-zend-mail-function-error-included-code .If you need any more details please fell free to ask me ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please update to the latest ZF stable branch.

As a quickfix, you should try to replace your code with this :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'my name')
         ->setFrom('myemanil@gmail.com', 'my name')
         ->setSubject('My Subject')
         ->setBodyText('Email Body');
$mail->send();
```

Depending on the ZF version you are using, method chaining could be the problem here.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for the reply I'm using the latest version of zf ...

but what you said didn't work for me ...

Answer (score 0):

try like this
example from my project

```
  $options = array(
        'auth'     => 'login',
        'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl'      => 'tls',
        'port' => 587
    );
    $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $options);
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);

$m = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$m->setHeaderEncoding(Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);

    $m->addTo("username@gmail.com");
    $m->setFrom('username2b@gmail.com', 'username');
    $m->setSubject('usertext');
    $errortext = "report";
    $m->setBodyHtml($errortext, 'UTF-8', Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
    $m->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the default transport for your application. Where you are writing the code, in the constructor of the class, you have to use this.

```
function __construct() {
    $tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(<your smtp IP address>);
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);
}
```

Note: Along with the above code, please check in your php.ini file of your apache server for the following setting. The below option should be uncommented.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```